# Typescript array foreach with push function (Angular)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have array:

```
data
    Array
    (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name0] => J
            [name1] => L
            [name2] => C
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [data0] => 3,1,3
            [data1] => 5,3,2
            [Nu0] => 3,0,0
            [Nu1] => 1,1,1
        )

)
```

I need push the data to other array

```
this.datas.push({'name':'A','data':(data[1].data0).'color':'#00000'}); 
this.datas.push({'name':'C','data':(data[1].Nu0).'color':'#00000'}); 
this.datas.push({'name':'B','data':(data[1].data1).'color':'#FFFFF'}); 
this.datas.push({'name':'D','data':(data[1].Nu1).'color':'#FFFFF'}); 
this.namedatas.push(data[0].name0);
this.namedatas.push(data[0].name1);
```

How to use loop function to do this? Also what to do if I have more data?

Comment: 1. Share the data array as valid json 2. What is the other array that you are trying to push to? 3. What is the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

In your case I suggest you to use a map or a filter function:

```
metadas = datas.map((el) => {
    return el.name;
});
```

In this case in metadatas array you will have all names contained into datas array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do easily like below in this example we are going to push data from first array `items` to second array `newItems`:

Like this is your first array `items`:

```
const items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
```

This is your second array `newItems`:

```
const newItems = []
```

Here is your solution :

```
items.forEach(function(item){
  newItems.push(item)
})
```

Comment: if I need the data0 then null0 then data1 then null1 in the new array, how to us loop to do it?

Comment: You have do like patten, loop inside loop, it means subarray loop.